# php sqlite3 working, but sqlite3Database() not working after installing php5-sqlite

Tags: php, sqlite

I am trying to use sqlite using php .

I have installed sqlite using

```
sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite
```

then I added

```
extension = sqlite3.so to the php.ini file .
```

After doing this,

```
$db = new SQLite3("FgH");
```

above command not working but,PHP DETECTING SQLite3 above .

But, if i use

```
$db = new SQLiteDatabase("DfG");
```

above command saying SQLiteDatabase is not found .  I tried combinations like Sqlite3Database, SQLiteDatabase3, SQLiteDatabase ,   None of them worked  .

Whats the solution,
thanks